# How does this SQL COALESCE Function Work?

Tags: sql, coalesce

I am using some code I found on a website and I just can't get my brain around this.

```
   SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [DATE], 106) + ']', 
           '[' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [DATE], 106) + ']')
           FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT [DATE] FROM #DailyReport ) PV  order by [DATE]
```

It returns

```
  [02 May 2016],[03 May 2016],[04 May 2016],[05 May 2016],[06 May 2016],[08 May 2016],[09 May 2016],[10 May 2016],[11 May 2016],[12 May 2016],[13 May 2016],[15 May 2016],[16 May 2016],[17 May 2016],[18 May 2016],[19 May 2016],[20 May 2016],[22 May 2016],[23 May 2016],[24 May 2016],[25 May 2016],[26 May 2016],[27 May 2016],[29 May 2016],[30 May 2016],[31 May 2016]
```

but how does it work?  I wish I understood how I got all those columns and why there are two   '[' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [DATE], 106) + ']' phrases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two phrases you point out are simply so `coalesce()` works.  There is a simpler way to write the logic.  Perhaps this will help explain what happens:

```
SELECT @cols = COALESCE(@cols + ',', '') + '[' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255), [DATE], 106) + ']',
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [DATE] FROM #DailyReport
     ) PV  
ORDER BY [DATE];
```

In your case, the full concatenation is the first argument to `COALESCE()`, so the expression is needed as the first argument.  But, if that is `NULL`, then it is needed again.

Note:  When use use `VARCHAR()`, `NVARCHAR()` or any character type in SQL Server, you should *always* include a length specifier.  The default length varies by context, and if the default is not large enough, the bug can be very difficult to track down.